# Twitter Boostrap 3 carousel Not Animating in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

Twitter Bootstrap Carousel Animation not transiting in Firefox but works excellently well on Chrome.  I even tried the sample code from [GetBoostrap official website](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) on Firefox but it still does not transit but just a quick change without noticing any effect.

Never got a working sample from SO on what to do.

My code snippet

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="/static/img/2.png">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3 style="color:#000">First slide label </h3>
                <p style="color:#000">Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item ">
            <img src="/static/img/1.png">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3 style="color:#000">Second slide label </h3>
                <p style="color:#000">Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item ">
            <img src="/static/img/4.png">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3 style="color:#000">Third slide label </h3>
                <p style="color:#000">Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <span class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev" id="left-btn" onmouseover=setCursorByID("left-btn","pointer")>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="color:#999999" ></span>
    </span>

    <span class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next" id="right-btn" onmouseover=setCursorByID("right-btn","pointer")>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="color:#999999" ></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Can any one please give me proper direction on what to do?

Comment: Try again, the sample slider works fine for me. (ff24). Make sure you have the needed js / images and whatever resourceres are needed

Comment: @RonniSkansing I tried it on FF14 and not working. And that is what the company am helping out is using.What should i do?

Comment: just to make sure i get it right, when you go to the bootstrap page and look at the example slider, this is also not working? or only when you try to apply it another page?

Comment: yes it is not working from the sample slider on the bootstrap page. I opened the same url on chrome and it was animating so fine but on FF no show. this is the link http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: I can not reproduce it here. You should set which browsers and which versions are the lowst that should work. If the client demands that it works on older browser, you just ask for more money and spend time fixing it. A good place to start would be in the developer toolbar (console), check if there are any errors.

Comment: Thanks very much @RonniSkansing I quickly compared the same code with a higher version of Firefox(27 latest). And in-fact, the code works excellently well. Now, I can say that it is a browser compatibility issue. So I will have to take your advise and tell the company that they need an upgrade for better performances not just in this code but for future purposes. Thanks once more.

Comment: No problem. Asking the client to upgrade is often the ideal solution. Fallbacks and graceful degradation are also solutions you can look into if needed later on. Feel free to answer this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

After the help out from [Ronny Skansing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/924016/ronni-skansing). I was able to figure the common problem to this issue.

Make sure that you always use the **latest browsers** for Twitter Bootstrap 3.* **Carousel animation transition** to work for you on Mozilla FF.

Though if you are looking for backward compatibility. You can on your own look for solutions if you indeed want to fallback or for graceful degradation. Thanks